xrandr command fails after suspend/resume
I have dual monitors. For a while I have been using this command in a script to make a joined desktop
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --output DP-0 --auto --left-of HDMI-0

This still works from a cold boot, but after suspend/resume I get
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  50

And the monitors duplicate each other instead of joining.
This happened before and after upgrade to 24.04.

OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080/PCIe/SSE2

